# Data Transfer Object: как инициализировать и должны ли быть геттеры?

Tags: php, dto

Недавно узнал о паттерне `DTO`, до этого в приложении мои методы возвращали массивы - и это был ад их рефакторить. Теперь понял, что этот паттерн сильно упростит разработку.

Посмотрел несколько примеров, как работают с этим паттерном, я честно говоря, мнения очень разные, а именно:

Одни говорят, что `Data Transfer Object` не должен иметь никаких методов, должны быть только свойства.
Другие, добавляют в эти объекты геттеры, чтобы вызывать свои свойства через них.
Также, видел варианты, когда создают какой-то один абстрактный класс для `DTO` в котором реализуют функционал инициализации свойств через конструктор (в конструктор принимается массив `ключ => знач`), и соответствующим свойствам выставляются значения.

Не совсем понял, как правильно должно это быть..
Можно ли делать геттеры (они же никакую логику не задают) ? 
Как быть с инициализацией данных ? И какие есть варианты аниверсальной инициализации через родительский класс 0 если так можно ?

Простая инициализация `DTO` мне больше нужна чем геттеры, т.к. очень хочется писать так:

```
return new myDTO(["key" => "val"]);
```

или еще как-нибудь если есть варианты ? 
Чтобы не писать так:

```
$dto = new myDTO();
$dto->param1 = $value1;
...
```

Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Можно для создания юзать один класс, после заполнения всех необходимых данных просто передавать его в конструктор dto, аля `$song = new Song(); $song->name='sName';$song->extension='mp3';$dto=new DTO($song);`